# Shared functions between already extended classes

Tags: php, oop

I am looking to tidy up some code I have inherited. Essentially we have two classes (A + B) that extend off two separate classes that do various things differently, however A and B also share some functions. At present the functions are copy and pasted between the two and obviously I know this is wrong. I am looking to see if there it a solution to this so that I only have to define the functions once so that both A and B can use these. Any help would be great!

Comment: Composition is an alternative to Inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From php 5.4 you could use [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Here is example from manual

```
<?php
trait ezcReflectionReturnInfo {
    function getReturnType() { /*1*/ }
    function getReturnDescription() { /*2*/ }
}

class ezcReflectionMethod extends ReflectionMethod {
    use ezcReflectionReturnInfo;
    /* ... */
}

class ezcReflectionFunction extends ReflectionFunction {
    use ezcReflectionReturnInfo;
    /* ... */
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Good practise to use?

Comment: @Dogday , it's not good practice for me. But I know who use it. Anyway it's better than copy&paste.

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world, it's possible that what you really want there is multiple inheritance, but that is not supported by PHP (or many other languages) as it is much more complex than single inheritance.

One alternative to consider is arranging your code so that both classes eventually inherit from some common ancestor, so that you can put your code here. This may not always be desirable or practical, however, particularly if some of the classes extended are from different libraries with no shared dependency.

You might be able to alter the ancestry of some of your classes by using "composition" and "delegation" rather than direct inheritance. The basic idea is that rather than class B extending class A, you store an instance of class A as a property of class B; when certain methods of class B are called, they call corresponding methods of the A instance, while other methods of B are completely separate, and can be inherited from somewhere else. The [magic method __call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) can be useful for implementing this without having to know every possible delegated method in advance.

As of PHP 5.4, there is a form of ["horizontal code reuse" called Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). Traits are sometimes described as "compiler-assisted copy-and-paste", because they don't represent any OOP relationship between the classes where they are used, only a way of editing the functions in one place.

If the functions are public, you might want to [declare the classes as implementing an Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php), which lets other code check that a set of methods are available, usually by using the `instanceof` operator. This can be used in combination with a Trait, which contains the details of *how* those methods are implemented.